# Bukkit config.yml resets when changing data

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit

I have a problem with my config.yml file. When I start my
 
Plugin it automatically generates the default ***config.yml***
file. This is the default preset:

```
#This Plugin was made by Yuki
#Version 0.0.1
Spawn:
  World: 
  X: 
  Y: 
  Z: 
  Yaw: 
  Pitch:
```

I've created a comment(/setspawn), which enters the data in
the config.yml. This part works fine, with the little issue,
that every time the config.yml gets wiped completely.
config.yml after inserting data:

```
Spawn:
  World: world
  X: -155.45080613398784
  Y: 82.0
  Z: -57.60431500946787
  Yaw: -27.600231
  Pitch: 29.550203
```

I insert the data with the following lines:

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if(sender instanceof Player) {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if(sender.hasPermission("cc.command.setSpawn")) {
            FileConfiguration config = Main.getPlugin().getConfig();
            config.set("Spawn.World", player.getWorld().getName());
            config.set("Spawn.X", player.getLocation().getX());
            config.set("Spawn.Y", player.getLocation().getY());
            config.set("Spawn.Z", player.getLocation().getZ());
            config.set("Spawn.Yaw", player.getLocation().getYaw());
            config.set("Spawn.Pitch", player.getLocation().getPitch());
            Main.getPlugin().saveConfig();
            player.sendMessage("Der Spawn wurde gesetzt!");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    private static Main plugin;

    public void onEnable() {
        plugin = this;
        this.saveDefaultConfig();
        System.out.println("\033[1;36m"+"["+"\033[1;35m"+"CC"+"\033[1;36m"+"]"+"\033[0;35m"+"Crystal Cake is online"+"\033[0m");
        //commands
        getCommand("heal").setExecutor(new HealAndFood());
        getCommand("setspawn").setExecutor(new SetSpawnCommand());

        //Listeners
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new JoinLeaveListener(), this);
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(new KillListener(), this);

    }

    public void onDisable() {
        System.out.println("\033[1;36m"+"["+"\033[1;35m"+"CC"+"\033[1;36m"+"]"+"\033[0;35m"+"Crystal Cake is offline"+"\033[0m");

    }

    public static Main getPlugin() {
        return plugin;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include the onEnable() code.

I am guessing that there is something in there which does the equivalent of `saveDefaultConfig()` when starting the plugin. :)

EDIT: I have copied you code into another plugin of mine. I have no problems. After starting the server, the config stays as intended. Are there any messages in the logs?

Comment: Oki. I've added the whole main class

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: No? Mhm... my plugin overwrite the config.yml every time... and nope there are no messages in the log

Comment: @Yuki If you delete the current config, it comes back after restart right?

Comment: the plugin generates the default config.yml(first content in the grey box), but when I want to insert the data behind the empty points(World: , X: e.t.c.) it deletes the comments and everything else in the config file

Comment: Is it able to read the file? (I am think folder or file permission problems)
Other possibility: You have a copyDefaults() somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes the file is readable and no there is no copy Defaults()...

Comment: Well, I don't really know what to say know :/ Try on another pc? With no other plugins aka clean install? I would ask to see the entire project, but I doubt anyone would hand over their projects completely...

Comment: I wouldn't have a problem with sending you the complete project data. But for now, I`ve tried it with a new version of Java and other programms. I hope it will work now.